# Is Webpack DevServer too slow or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a React project that I bundle using Webpack.
The project is small and has only 3 dependencies: `react`, `react-dom` and `react-router-dom`.
I am using the Webpack DevServer for development and it consistently takes about **8 seconds** to recompile the project.

My question is, is this how long Webpack normally takes to recompile a small project? Or am I doing something wrong?

My `webpack.config.js` file looks like this:

```js
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");

const config = {
  // ...
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    compress: true,
    port: 9000,
    hot: true,
  },
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: It's supposed to take about a few seconds but wouldn't take up to 8s :)

Comment: What hardware are you using?

Comment: MacBook Pro early 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create react app has a very fast compile time maybe you should consider using it. Otherwise the webpack plugin react hot loader might solve your problem: https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader

Answer (score 1):

[`compress: true,` tells webpack to use gzip compression.](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devservercompress)

Afaik it's kinda slow, so you probably shouldn't use it for development (apart from testing/debugging).

Try removing that line and check out how much time it takes.

Comment: I already tried that. No difference at all.